# Events in Node.js

Tags: node.js, eventemitter

First example from https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/child_process.html is as follows:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

ls.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`)
});
```

Isn't it wrong as in fact the process (in this case ls) may end up before one starts reacting to events so basically one will miss them.

Answer (score 0):

No. While `ls` is a "blocking" process itself, the spawning of a childprocess in node is async, i.e. the above code spins up a new process, registers the event handlers and then when the process is ready to run commands it'll execute `ls`.